# Insist+ that-clause

Tags: word-usage, subjunctives, mandative

I have a question regarding the correct usage of 'insist' in a sentence.

So, I don't know which one I should write:

> 1. My mother insisted **that I should stay** at home for a couple of days due to my illness.

or,

> 2. My mother insisted **that I am staying** at home for a couple of days due to my illness.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the definition, [***insist***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/insist) by itself does not make anything happen.

So you should use *should* since it is natural to consider doing what your mother says, but you certainly don't have to. (In this statement I also use "should", since it is my recommendation but ultimately your choice how to say it.)

So it is correct to say:

> My mother insisted that I **should** stay at home for a couple of days due to my illness.

*am* is better suited to a statement where something will certainly be done. For example:

> I don't care what my mother says, I **am** going to that party.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. My mother insisted **that I should stay** at home for a couple of days due to my illness.

This sentence is okay.

> 2. My mother insisted **that I am staying** at home for a couple of days due to my illness.

This sentence is okay grammaticaly, but the meaning is off kilter: it does not say that your mother *wanted* you to stay at home.

What it means is that your mother was telling *to someone* (maybe even to you) that you are at home for a couple of days due to your illness. She was telling this in an *insistent* manner, but she wasn't commanding anybody to stay at home. She was trying to convince, not to command.

We can transform sentence 2 in a sentence equal in meaning to sentence 1:

> My mother insisted **that I stay** at home for a couple of days due to my illness.

Such construction is called "*[mandative subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive)*" and is used to express a circumstance that is demanded, desired, etc.

The Wikipedia article on subjunctive points out the possible confusion between the indicative and subjunctive mood in sentences with *insist, suggest* and *propose*:

> I insist that he **is** here (indicative, a forceful assertion of the fact that he is here)
>   I insist that he **be** here (subjunctive, a demand that the condition of his being here be fulfilled)